# Public Function for Notification View

Tags: ios, swift

I've created a custom NotificationView, which i'm using in almost every viewController, which mean i have below function in all viewControllers. Is there way to only have it in one, so it is not repeated a lot of times?

**variables**

```
var notification:SFSwiftNotification?
var notificationFrame:CGRect?
```

**function**

```
func setUpNotification() {
    //Notification Setup
    notificationFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetMaxX(self.view.frame), 64)
    notification = SFSwiftNotification(frame: notificationFrame!,
        title: nil,
        image: "Error",
        animationType: AnimationType.AnimationTypeCollision,
        direction: Direction.TopToBottom, delegate: self)
    notification!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    notification!.label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.6)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.addSubview(notification!)
}
```

Comment: why you not make it in AppDelegate and call this from all viewController

Comment: How could this look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `extension` which is, exactly what it sounds like, an extension to an object. So if you create an extension for `UIViewController` then all objects that inherit from the UIViewController will be able to use this extension. So you create a .swift-file that looks like this:

```
var notification:SFSwiftNotification?
var notificationFrame:CGRect?

extension UIViewController: SFSwiftNotificationProtocol  {


        func setUpNotification() {
        //Notification Setup
        notificationFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetMaxX(self.view.frame), 64)
        notification = SFSwiftNotification(frame: notificationFrame!,
            title: nil,
            image: "Error",
            animationType: AnimationType.AnimationTypeCollision,
            direction: Direction.TopToBottom, delegate: self)
        notification!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        notification!.label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.6)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.addSubview(notification!)
        }
}
```

In all your ViewControllers you can now just do: `self.setUpNotification()`.

### Edit

Added `SFSwiftNotificationProtocol` in `extension UIViewController: SFSwiftNotificationProtocol`.

Comment: I guess i would need to do the same for UITableViewController

Comment: i cant set the delegate to self here? since i cant add `SFSwiftNotificationProtocol`

Comment: you can add SFSwiftNotificationProtocol here as well. Check updated code.

Comment: `UIViewController` does not conform `SFSwiftNotificationProtocol`

Comment: You get that error because you state that you are going to implement SFSwiftNotificationProtocol here, thus you have to add the functions that are required for this protocol. It's hard to right of the bat if this is the way to go. What more functions are you using inside your ViewControllers that are connected to the SFSwiftNotificationProtocol?

Comment: The protocol conform following method `func didNotifyFinishedAnimation(results: Bool)` however i would like to call this in the viewController itself. is that possible?

Comment: No, it won't be possible. This needs to be in the extension as well. I suppose you could add it in the extension, but override it in your ViewController where you'd like it to be used. Hard to say without trying, I don't know for sure. Is it possible for you to upload your project or a sample project that I can try with?

Comment: or not cant have stored properties in extension so `notification` return nil

Comment: I can't think of another way to do it with extension, other than sending in the object as a parameter which should be the delegate. But that is not a very neat solution. Especially if you have different classes as objects. Would be easier to help you find a proper solution if you could upload some sample project :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create one `UIViewController`, realize your func in it, and inherit all your controllers from this root controller.

if you have `UITableViewController`

```
YourViewController : RootVC <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Dont forget to write delegate methods, and add `UITableView` on your view

Comment: Well what will i do when i have a TableViewController?

Comment: UITableViewController is inherited from UIViewController, just have UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource protocols realized. 
You can just change 1 line of code and have same thing: class YourTableViewController: NotificationViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource. And NotificationViewController has your Notification inside.